# How to Restore custom Territory Management data in Enterprise Territory Management?

Tags: territory-management

Recently we have switched from Custom Territory Management to Enterprise Territory Management. During this transition we have lost our data. (I am Not able to see any territory hierarchy / rule anymore in new version ETM).

However I have taken full back up of ORG before proceeding and now wish to restore those settings in new version. Is there a way to do this?